# I need to extract a specific word after a word using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this series:

```
[Spanish | Intermediate; Portuguese | Native; English | Advanced,
French | Intermediate; Spanish | Native; English | Native,
Spanish | Native; English | Intermediate,
Portuguese | Native; English | Intermediate; Spanish | Intermediate ]
```

I want to use regex to extract the Spanish followed by the level like; `Spanish | Native`.

I used:

```
y =[]
for i in la:
    x = re.findall(r"[Spanish+[^a-z]+[^a-z]+[^a-z]+"
                   r"Intermediate|Advanced|Native|Beginner]", i)
    y.append(x)
```

but not good result.

Comment: Is what you have a string?

Comment: You are using `[` `]` for a character class, but you can use a capture group instead `\bSpanish \| (Intermediate|Advanced|Native|Beginner)\b` https://regex101.com/r/qznLvi/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the groups of `Language | Level`, you can use `\w+\s\|\s\w+`. This looks for a word, then whitespace, then a pipe, then whitespace, then a word.

Comment: But I think the OP is looking for the word Spanish in particular.

Comment: But what if i want only Spanish language

Comment: Then you can include the second half in a non-capturing group `(\w+)(?:\s\|\s\w+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
y =[]
for i in la:
    x = re.findall(r"Spanish.*?\|(.*?);", i)
    y.append(x)
```

This would extract & return all the levels associated with Spanish language.
The pattern is `Spanish` then `.*?` means any characters in non greedy way then followed by `|` symbol then again `.*?` means any characters in non greedy way followed by `semicolon`
The bracket around `.*?` means return only the levels

Comment: With the semicolon it will miss the last occurrence `Spanish | Intermediate ]`  https://regex101.com/r/Ty88Yp/1